# FCM Notification not working in Chinese phone when app remove from recent

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have Test my app in motorola , samsung working fine when app is killed. but when i test app in vivo, oppo not working in case of app is destroyed.

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

if (remoteMessage == null)
    return;

// Check if message contains a notification payload.
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    //  handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

// Check if message contains a data payload.
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        handleDataMessage(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Android Manifest xml:

```
 <service
    android:name="notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name="notification.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also i have implement these line in my main class to start autostart,

```
      Intent intent = new Intent();
    String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    System.out.println("manufacturer : "+manufacturer);
    switch (manufacturer) {
        case "xiaomi":
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            break;
        case "oppo":
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
            // intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oppo.safe", "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
            break;
        case "vivo":
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
            break;
        case "Honor":
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
            break;
        /*case "samsung":
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.samsung.android.lool", "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity"));
            break;*/
        case "htc":
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.htc.pitroad", "com.htc.pitroad.landingpage.activity.LandingPageActivity"));
            break;
        case "asus":
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.asus.mobilemanager", "com.asus.mobilemanager.MainActivity"));
            break;
    }
    List<ResolveInfo> arrayList =  getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (arrayList.size() > 0) { startActivity(intent); }
```

But notification not getting by these line in case of oppo.

Answer (score 0):

Remove from recent task, system will kill the app immediately. So, do not do this.

Firebase was blocked by GFW in China. Google service can not used in China. If you want to use Firebase in China, enable a VPN.

Since 8.0, API have limit: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Outside China, no network problem. OEM system had them own background behavior restriction. Even if not remove from recent, when app on the background, it will been killed. Even if service startForeground(), they don't follow the API behavior.
It's hard to keep any background service. Users must add it to whitelist first. But every OEM system have a different way.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not an answer to the question. You have to post it on the comment's section.

Comment: @cod-e-rection I changed my answer. Hope to help.

Comment: @HarishRawal No programmably way to enter the whitelist.  "com.samsung.android.lool" not exists, tested on my Samsung S8(China). Many years ago, locked app in recent list will added to whitelist(Mi 4c MIUI 6 Android 5.1). But locked app in recent list can not keep running in Samsung S8.